# Get folder used space on a NAS C#

Tags: c#, size, directory, nas, shared-directory

Is there a way using C# to get a folder size (used space on drive) located on a NAS or on a network shared directory I.e.: \\myNASdrive\MediaFiles?

I already tried something like this:

```
string[] a = Directory.GetFiles(p, "*.*");
long b = 0;
foreach (string name in a)
{       
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
    b += info.Length;
}   
return b;
```

But this works for local folders only.

Also we've tried using user impersonation but with no results.

Comment: Try looking into `WMI` would be my first thought or `DirectoryInfo` Class

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kraze! I've tried that before, but it gives me an UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: If this code is in the Windows service, then you have to run this service with account that has rights (user that has created the folder) on the folder created on NAS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the right permissions, this should do it;

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DiskFreeSpaceEx
{
    internal class FreeSpace
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern int GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,ref long    lpFreeBytesAvailable,ref long lpTotalNumberOfBytes,ref long lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
        const string RootPathName = @"\\server\share";
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long freeBytesAvailable = 0;
            long totalNumberOfBytes = 0;
            long totalNumberOfFreeBytes = 0;

            GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(RootPathName, ref freeBytesAvailable, ref
               totalNumberOfBytes, ref totalNumberOfFreeBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", RootPathName,
                freeBytesAvailable, totalNumberOfBytes, totalNumberOfFreeBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Uses P/Invoke to get the information. Make sure you change the server and share.